# How to remove file details while running a Talend job using command lines

Tags: command-line, talend

I am running a talend job using a command line.
While running it prints out the entire code under batch file.

which goes like..

java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp ../lib/advancedPersistentLookupLib-1.0.jar;../lib/commons-collections-3.2.jar;../lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar;....

How do I remove that? I don't want that code to appear in command line while running my job.

Comment: :D I felt if it don't show all those arguments it would look cleaner.

Comment: Why don't you want it there?

Comment: I am printing messages through my job and thought it would look cleaner without these batch files argument. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I added '@echo off' before those arguments and '@echo on' after them.
And it worked.